# add items to another list and remove from there with React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am newbie in React js. I am trying to do Pokedex app. I was able to fetc data via Api list them. And I made  detail page  for each pokemon. In this detail page I have one button  to favorite this pokemon and move it to favorite list and show it when I clicked favorites in navbar. I want to see it. Also I will do the opposite of it (remove from favorites).  I have been trying for almost 3 days and I am so confused. Please it is really import for me. I am not sure what cıde should I add, So I am giving my project link. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

pokemonFav.js

```
 function PokemonFav(){
 const [fullList, setFullList] = useState([])
 const [favList, setFavList] = useState([]) 

 const handleFavAddClick=(e)=>{
     setFavList(preState=>[...preState, e])
     setFullList(preState=> preState.filter(item => item !== e))
 }


 return(
     <div>
         Full List
         <ul>
          {
              fullList.map(e=> <li key={e} onClick={()=>handleFavAddClick(e)}>{e}</li>)
          }
         </ul>

         Fav List
         <ul>
          {
              favList.map(e=> <li key={e}>{e}</li>)
          }
         </ul>
     </div>
 )
}
  export default PokemonFav;
```

pokemoncard.js
I added the button here and call the handlefavadclick function
like so

```
   <button  key={e} onClick={()=>handleFavAddClick(e)}>{e}</button>
```

https://github.com/yasoyase/Pokedex-app

Comment: You might find that folks would be more willing to help if you made it easy for them. Try posting a code snippet of the issue you're having.

Comment: I edited. Hope someone will see. and heelp

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [fullList, setFullList] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "List1" },
    { id: 2, name: "List2" }
  ]);
  const [favList, setFavList] = useState([]);

  const handleFavAddClick = (e) => {
 // we find the item with current id
    const findItem = fullList.find((item) => item.id === e);
    if (findItem) {
      const checkIfIsFav = favList.find((item) => item.id === e);
      // if the item is not in fav list add it, else remove it
      if (!checkIfIsFav) {
        setFavList([...favList, findItem]);
      } else {
        setFavList(favList.filter((item) => item.id !== e));
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      Full List
      <ul>
        {fullList.map((e) => {
          const isFav = favList.find((item) => item.id === e.id);
          return (
            <div className="flex">
              <li key={e.id}>{e.name}</li>
              <button onClick={() => handleFavAddClick(e.id)}>
                {isFav ? "Unfav" : "Fav"}
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      Fav List
      <ul>
        {favList.map((e) => (
          <li key={e.id}>{e.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```